# Can I travel with a Geneva convention 1951 travel document to Australia without visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia, german-citizens

I have a German Geneva convention 1951 travel document and I will visit Australia, do I need to apply for a visa?

Answer (score 10):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=SR&COUNTRY=AU&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by the airlines for passport and visa requirements, Australia requires a visa for visitors traveling on refugee travel documents:

> Visa required.