# If I have German travel document for refugees do I need visa to Visit Australia?

Tags: visas, germany, australia, refugees

If I have German travel document for refugees do I need visa to Visit  Australia? And what is the best visa to travel to Australia to attend my daughters wedding?

Comment: Australia's borders are [currently closed](https://www.health.gov.au/news/health-alerts/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-health-alert/coronavirus-covid-19-restrictions/coronavirus-covid-19-advice-for-international-travellers). Close family members of Australian citizens and permanent residents can enter, but you should verify that you will be able to enter for this purpose before you worry about a visa.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I travel with a Geneva convention 1951 travel document to Australia without visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94095/can-i-travel-with-a-geneva-convention-1951-travel-document-to-australia-without)

Comment: I just want to make sure that OP doesn't confuse "Austria" (which is next to Germany and is called "Österreich" in german) and "Australia" (which is on the other side of the globe, seen from Germany).

Comment: re: @orithena Sign seen is Austria: "There are no kangaroos in Austria". :)

Comment: @FreeMan http://www.itchyfeetcomic.com/2020/02/wrong-hemisphere.html :-)

Answer (score 12):

Currently, Australian borders are closed with few exceptions to foreign nationals due to Covid-19 pandemic. Parents of an independent adult are not considered immediate family for the purpose of exemptions. Weddings are also not usually considered a compassionate and compelling reason to travel.

At this time, even if you obtain a visa, you won't be allowed to come to Australia without good reasons and an exemption by the Australian government.

https://covid19.homeaffairs.gov.au/coming-australia

---

When things return to the normal:

Yes, Australia requires a visitor visa for holders of 1951 Convention travel documents (blue).

Only a citizen of Germany (or other eligible countries) with a valid passport is eligible to visit Australia under eVisitor scheme.

> You cannot apply with:
>
> - a non-citizen passport, certificate of identity or other travel document
>
> https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/evisitor-651#Eligibility

You can apply under the tourist stream or sponsored family stream (if your daughter is eligible). You can find more information here: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600.